# Create Numbers file and open it with Numbers on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, numbers, document

I would like to do a task that is quite simple on other OS, but it is not so trivial on iOS. Namely, I want to create file and open it in Numbers.
I can preview the file with UIDocumentInteractionController and then offer it to user that he/she opens it.
THis seems to me quite a reasonable solution. However, I need to offer proper file format. I suppose CSV and XLS would be reasonable to implement and it would most probably work, but I would still like to do it in native Numbers format if possible. However, I can't find any info about this file format.

Basically, this task is about exporting data to another app and then working further with them.

Comment: Thanks, Joe :) I always encourage people to correct me whenever I make any kind of spelling and/or grammar mistake. Since I work in international environment, I communicate daily in 4 languages including mother tongue and mistakes are inevitable. No hard feelings?

Comment: Yes, new about Edit, don't know why I haven't used it already. Like my favorite movie character said looking himself in the mirror in the morning: "Every day in every way I improve myself..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a library that can create native Numbers files. There are hoewever some libraries that allow creating XLS files. Since Numbers fully supports XLS, this is probably the way to go.

There is a comercial library available that might work on the iPhone (costs $200): http://www.libxl.com/

As for free XLS libraries, I only know [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/), a Python module. You could set up a webservice that creates an XLS file for your app, using xlwt on the server side.

Comment: Thanks, Jakob. Library makes a good sense to use if it is already there. Especially, since I haven't written any parser/creator for .XLS.

Comment: most likely libxl won't work on the iphone. They won't give you the source code. They'll give you a universal library for mac, which won't run on the iphone.

Comment: Yeah, I just remembered libxl off the top of my head, I just checked the website, and there IS a source code option, but it costs $2000, and there's no guarantee it will compile on the iPhone. If you need xls support on the iPhone, you should probably contact the author of libxl -- I'd be interested in their response.

Comment: Hm, I need to pass pretty much simple information to Numbers. For 2K I can write it by myself and no problems with anyone about anything...But it's worth asking anyway :)

Comment: I contacted the developers of LibXL. They answered that they do not offer libXL for iOS and they have not tried compiling it on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass information to Numbers, you can probably also use CSV files. If you use CSV files, you must be aware of some things. There are two kinds of CSV files: the comma separated version (used in english speaking countries) and the semicolon separated (used in continental europe).

The comma separated CSV files look for example like this:

```
"ID","First Name","Last Name","Salary"
1,"John","Malkovich",3400.20
2,"Fred","Astaire",2000.60
```

The second kind of CSV files are semicolon separated and use a comma as decimal mark. They look like this:

```
"ID";"First Name";"Last Name";"Salary"
1;"John";"Malkovich";3400,20
2;"Fred";"Astaire";2000,60
```

On the Macintosh, Numbers expects a different format depending on the Region setting. If you have your Region set to the US, it will expect the first kind. If you choose Germany, it will expect the second kind.

I don't know what kind of files Numbers on the iPad expects.

Another alternative would be using copy and paste. Try to copy tab separated text into the clipboard.

Comment: Yes, these are all legitimate ideas and work on Mac OS X. I just have to test it in iOS environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you. I've contacted libxl team and they responded with the link to the demo version of their iPhone library: http://www.libxl.com/download/libxl-iphone.zip